# How do indices work in a list with duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indices

I'm trying to understand how lists and indices work in python.

So I tried this code to print every item in a list and its corresponding index in the list:

```
tokens = ["and", "of", "then", "and", "for", "and"]
for word in tokens:
    word_index = tokens.index(word)
    print(word_index, word)
```

It gives me this output:

```
0 and
1 of
2 then
0 and
4 for
0 and
```

So my question is why `"and"` here always have the same index of `0` instead of `0, 3, 5`?
(and how do I get the desired output).

```
0 and
1 of
2 then
3 and
4 for
5 and
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is why "and" here have the same index of 0 instead of 0, 3, 5?

**Why**

It's because [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) returns the index of the first occurrence, so since "and" first appears in index 0 in the list, that's what you'll always get.

**Solution**

If you want to follow the index as you go try [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
    print(i, token)
```

**Which gives the output you want:**

```
0 and
1 of
2 then
3 and
4 for
5 and
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate`.

```
In [1]: tokens = ["and", "of", "then", "and", "for", "and"]
In [2]: for word_index,word in enumerate(tokens):
   ....:     print (word_index, word)
   ....:
```

**Output**

```
0 and
1 of
2 then
3 and
4 for
5 and
```

Comment: Why down voted ? Even i answered right answer at the same time of the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), `index` returns the index of the first occurrence of the element in the list:

> `list.index(x)`
>
> Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.